# USB Tethering in host mode

Tags: usb-tethering, usb-peripherals, aosp, usb-modem

Using Android 9 running on a Quectel SOC with 1 USB port, I want to share the Android SOCs internet connection via ethernet over USB with another system (embedded Linux), but also allow USB host functions such as communicating with USB storage etc via a USB hub interface. Is this fundamentally possible (even if some AOSP modification is required on my part)?

From what I understand, native support is offered for the Android SOC to provide ethernet over USB as a USB device. What I want to achieve is provide ethernet over USB (and provide internet connection to peripherals) as a USB host. Is this support natively provided?

Comment: What device type used the Quectel modem when connected via USB (e.g. a virtual Ethernet network card)? Anyway small Cellphone-to-Wifi routers are usually the simpler solution.

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure I understand your question. I believe the Quectel modem when acting in the USB tethering mode represents a virtual ethernet interface. I will update the question with more info to counter your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I was totally confused by your question as I never heard of a modem running on Android. I am not sure if Android in embedded devices is really on-topic here - or does it has a screen with a UI like a smartphone?

Comment: No problem! Yes it has a UI and a screen and is effectively a smartphone. I will update my question again, as the term "modem" is a misnomer. It's an SoC.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct forum for this kind of question, as it gets into the technicality of the Android Linux Kernel USB support currently offered. But as I am working with AOSP on the whole and interfacing with an embedded Linux device, I thought that this might be the correct place.